# Displaying the last 3 news messages

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the last 3 news messages onto my PHP page. For that I am using the following code:

```
function news($number) {
    $number = (int)$number
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `author`, `message`, `date` 
                          FROM `news` 
                          WHERE `hidden` = 0 
                          ORDER BY `date` 
                          DESC LIMIT $number");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        return '<p class="p_sub">' . $row['title'] . '~' . $row['author'] .
           '</p><p>' . $row['message'] . '</p>';
        var_dump($row);
    }
}

echo news(3);
```

However, this only displays one message, not three. Anyone who can figure out why?

Comment: Oops, had to be 3 as well. I edited it now.

Comment: I now put return outside while now, but it still doesn not work: function news($number) {
 $number = (int)$number;
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `author`, `message`, `date` FROM `news` WHERE `hidden` = 0 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $number");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $result = '<p class="p_sub">' . $row['title'] . '~' . $row['author'] . '</p><p>' . $row['message'] . '</p>';
 }
 return $result;
}

echo news(3);

Comment: In the first iteration of the `while` loop, there is a `return` command, so the loop runs only once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `return` will exit your while loop. What you could do is concatenate a string containing your HTML like so

```php
$html = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $html .= '<p class="p_sub">' . $row['title'] . '~' . $row['author'] . '</p><p>' . $row['message'] . '</p>';                
}
return $html;
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! :D Thanks, I will accept your answer as soon as the website allows me to :P